# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I have uploaded my project on my hosting ..But when i tried to access form url I got the following Error

> ```
> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> ```

I have changed the following credentials of .env

```
DB_DATABASE=cpanel_database
DB_USERNAME=cpanel_db_name
DB_PASSWORD=cpanel_db_password
```

What could be the error for getting the Above Error?

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure your database credentials are correct. 
Might be chance that configurations run from cache. once clear is by login in server via ssh or remove config.php file from bootstrap/cache/ folder.

Good luck.

Comment: i tried a lot of things, but didn't touch the bootstrao/cache.
and after deleting this, it works for man. thanks man.

Comment: @Buchi Just remove all files from the bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not reading the credentials from your `.env` file. because it is reading root as the user instead of the username specified in the `.env`.

Check to make sure it is reading the `.env` and not the default parameters in the `config/database.php` file